# Mixed Q horn SAT

Tags: logic, algorithms, computational-complexity, np-complete, satisfiability

I am familiar with Horn formula: Formula whose clauses have atmost one positive literal.
I am also familiar with Mixed Horn formula: Formula whose clauses are either 2 CNF or Horn.

Question 1: But, what is meant by "mixed Quantified horn formula"?

We also know that,
Q3SAT problem: whether a Q3CNF formula is satisfiable.

Question 2:Is there a way to reduce Q3SAT to Mixed Quantified horn SAT problem?

Thank you

Comment: You might find better answers at the computer science stack exchange, http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

A mixed quantified Horn formula is a mixed Horn formula with quantifiers applied to the variables.  The Horn CNF formula

$(\lnot x_1\lor x_2) \land (x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3)$

is the same as the quantified formula

$\exists x_1\exists x_2\exists x_3$ $((\lnot x_1\lor x_2) \land (x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3))$

because by default existential quantification is assumed for variables in Boolean satisfiability problems.  But if quantification is specifically mentioned it usually means that [universal quantifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification) will also be used.  E.g.

$\exists x_1\forall x_2\exists x_3$ $((\lnot x_1\lor x_2) \land (x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3))$

Satisfying this formula requires that an assignment for $x_1$ exist such that for *all* assignments to $x_2$ there exists an assignment to $x_3$ that causes the formula to evaluate true.  The Wikipedia article on [quantified Boolean formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBF) covers this in greater detail.

As to the second question, whether a quantified 3SAT problem can be reduced to a quantified mixed Horn problem, the answer is yes.  Both 3SAT and mixed Horn SAT are NP-complete or $\Sigma_1^P$-complete languages.  All NP-complete problems are reducible to each other, as are all $\Sigma_n^P$-complete problems amongst themselves for a given $n$ and all $\Pi_n^P$-complete problems.  This covers Q3SAT and quantified mixed Horn SAT.

Comment: Thanks Kyle for the reply! I know how to reduce 3SAT to mixed horn. Is it going to be same for quantified formula. I think no

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is now solved!